# Sum column values where condition is met

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, filtering

I can't imagine this hasn't been asked before but here goes.

I extracted my values from an array.

```
foreach ($data as $gegevens) {
    $company = $gegevens['Name'];
    $value = $gegevens['Value'];
    
    if($company == 'Companyname'){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

This echoos out the individual values of the field `value` as long as the name matches. Works great, but now I want to know what the total is of those values counted. So the `sum` actually.

The results are always numbers; so countable but I don't know how.
I've seen that it is possible to count an array but it seems a little over the top to place these values in a new array!

Additional info because the total value should be in the same `foreach` loop

```
$last_company = "";
echo'<table><tr><td width="250">Bedrijfsnaam</td><td width="150">Factuur</td><td width="150">Gefactureerd bedrag</td><td width="200">Saldo</td>';
$sum=0;
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    $bedrijf = $gegevens['Naam'];
    $factuurnummer = $gegevens['Factuur'];
    $gefactureerd = $gegevens['Gefactureerd'];
    
    if($bedrijf == 'Companyname'){
        $sum += $gefactureerd;
    }
            
    if ($bedrijf == $last_company) {
        echo '<tr><td></td><td>'.$factuurnummer.'</td><td>'.$gefactureerd.'</td></tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$bedrijf.'</td><td>'.$factuurnummer.'</td><td>'.$gefactureerd.'</td><td>'.$sum.'</td></tr>';
        $last_company = $bedrijf;
    }
}   
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: $count++ in if condition

Comment: How about separating preparation of data and presentation?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I suggest to use english for naming variables, functions, classes, methods, and so on.

Comment: @localheinz Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
  $company = $gegevens['Name'];
  $value = $gegevens['Value'];

  if($company == 'Companyname'){
    $sum += $value;
  }
}   
echo $sum;
```

UPDATE: If you want an extremely simple solution:

```
$last_company = "";
echo'<table><tr><td width="250">Bedrijfsnaam</td><td width="150">Factuur</td><td width="150">Gefactureerd bedrag</td><td width="200">Saldo</td>';
$sum=0;
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    if($bedrijf == 'Companyname'){
        $sum += $gefactureerd;
    }
}

foreach ($data as $gegevens){
    $bedrijf = $gegevens['Naam'];
    $factuurnummer = $gegevens['Factuur'];
    $gefactureerd = $gegevens['Gefactureerd'];

    if ($bedrijf == $last_company) {
        echo '<tr><td></td><td>'.$factuurnummer.'</td><td>'.$gefactureerd.'</td></tr>';
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$bedrijf.'</td><td>'.$factuurnummer.'</td><td>'.$gefactureerd.'</td><td>'.$sum.'</td></tr>';
        $last_company = $bedrijf;
    }
}   
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: This works like it should. Problem now is that the outcome has to be in the `foreach` loop because the table is generated there. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about the table? Do you need the sum in every row? If so, you might need a separate loop to work out the sum beforehand and then output the table.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I placed the `$sum` within the `foreach` loop because this is where it should be in the end

Comment: Based on your updated code, you want to display the sum on every row, apart from the last one?

Comment: No I want only the total displayed

Comment: Reply to your updated answer. This is indeed what I had but the 'Companyname' was just for testing. I have a whole list of companies from a `csv` file. So the company name must be dynamically filled ;-)

Comment: Is this solution enough or do you need more help?

Comment: Well I just came to the following conclusion. The foreach loop checks the `csv`-file row-by-row. I want to have a `sum` of all the values from a company but that will never work. So I need to find a way to get the values outside the loop and add them while running.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = array();
foreach ($data as $gegevens){
  $company = $gegevens['Name'];
  $value = $gegevens['Value'];

  if($company == 'Companyname'){
    $sum [] = $value;
  }
}   
echo array_sum($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$filtered = array_filter($data, function (array $gegevens) {
    return $gegevens['Name'] === 'Companyname';
});

$total = array_sum(array_map(function (array $gegevens) {
    return $gegevens['Value'];
}, $filtered));
```

Comment: To get a total, *reducing* the list might be a better choice: `$total = array_reduce($filtered, function ($sum, $entry) { return $sum + $entry['Value']; }, 0);`